# WPF charting with multiple values on X axis

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, charts, wpftoolkit

I'm writing a WPF app that is supposed to display Charts. I am using WPF toolkit and cant seem to be able to create double categories, such as on the picture below. I'm new to WPF and XAML, so maybe this is an obvious fix.

I was also looking at ModernUI charts, but they dont seem to help either.

Any advice please?

Also, if you know of any better documented / easier to use charting for WPF that's free, do let me know.

This is the XAML that I have so far. I do not know how to add a second layer of independent variables.

```
    <charting:Chart x:Name="chart_res_eng" Margin="578,301,-1033,192">
        <charting:Chart.Series>
            <charting:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                DependentValuePath="Value"
                IndependentValuePath="Key"
                IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
        </charting:Chart.Series>
    </charting:Chart>
```

After this, I bind the DataContext to a KeyValuePair list.

**This is the output I'd like to achieve:**

[image: This is how the chart should look like]

Comment: Visiblox isn't free but it works great.  They have a trial version you can use that has a watermark.  You can also use Dynamic Data Display.

Comment: @mmathis: I have added the XAML part. THen I bind the DataContext to a KeyValuePair "list".

Comment: I tried to do this several years ago with Toolkit charts, but there is no easy way to do this except of rewriting the source code completely. So maybecomemrcial charts have such grouping feature, but I doubt this.

Comment: thank you vorrtex. I'll need to change some of my logic, then. Appreciate your response!